# How to enable Google map controllers (right,right..etc arrows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, google-maps

I have build an application to search my location.

Here is the code

```
var map;
var gdir;
var geocoder = null;
var addressMarker;   

function initialize() {
    if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {      
        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
        gdir = new GDirections(map, document.getElementById("directions"));
        GEvent.addListener(gdir, "load", onGDirectionsLoad);
        GEvent.addListener(gdir, "error", handleErrors);
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(51.519853,-0.122566), 14)
        var point = new GLatLng(51.519853,-0.122566); //CHANGE THESE COORDINATES
        map.addOverlay(new GMarker(point));
        map.openInfoWindow(map.getCenter(),html)
    }
}  

function setDirections(fromAddress) {
    gdir.load("from: " + fromAddress + " to: 51.519741,-0.122596 ");
}  

function handleErrors(){
    if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_UNKNOWN_ADDRESS) {
        alert("No corresponding geographic location could be found for one of the specified addresses. This may be due to the fact that the address is relatively new, or it may be incorrect.\nError code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
    } else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_SERVER_ERROR) {
       alert("A geocoding or directions request could not be successfully processed, yet the exact reason for the failure is not known.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);
    } else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_MISSING_QUERY) {
       alert("The HTTP q parameter was either missing or had no value. For geocoder requests, this means that an empty address was specified as input. For directions requests, this means that no query was specified in the input.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);           
    } else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_KEY) {
       alert("The given key is either invalid or does not match the domain for which it was given. \n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);    
    } else if (gdir.getStatus().code == G_GEO_BAD_REQUEST) {
       alert("A directions request could not be successfully parsed.\n Error code: " + gdir.getStatus().code);    
    } else {
       alert("An unknown error occurred.");
    }
}

function onGDirectionsLoad(){}
```

it is working fine. but there is no navigation keys. 
could any one tell me that how can I activate it please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to put different pan controls on the screen (e.g. the four directional icons commonly found on google maps), you may want to take a look at this [control tutorial](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html) for version 2 of the Google Maps Javascript API.

Basically, that link describes under what circumstances [which controls automatically appear](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/controls.html#Controls_overview). But, if you want to force controls into your google map, you can do it as follows:

```
function initialize() {
    //assuming 'map' already exists...
    //add a large pan / zoom control to the map
    map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
}
```

Comment: Which version of the Google Maps API are you using?

Comment: v2 


`<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;sensor=false&amp;key=ABQIAAAAzxCDBo1gy7W4QXIrmi9j2xTRTQz9XleK5_XejzX1GPWUDLY8xhSTdYSSU-w7OM78KatDMAVKJ-hHjw" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: Updated my answer. Please take a look.